What is the intuition behind a linear phase response having the a constant time delay for different frequencies?
In a linear phase system $\Omega(w) = k \cdot w$
how can the system have a constant time delay for different frequencies?
I'm trying to understand how a linear phase system with a transfer function defined as $\Omega(w) = k \cdot w$ behaves when a signal containing two frequencies, $w_1$ and $w_2$, passes through it.
I know that for an even magnitude response we can write
$$ H(e^{jw}) = |H(e^{jw})| \cdot e^{jkw}$$
From what I've read, a linear phase system introduces a constant time delay for all frequencies. However, from the above equation won't $w_1$ and $w_2$ end up being shifted to $k \cdot w_1$ and $k \cdot w_2$, respectively? How does this translate to a constant time delay for both frequencies?
Could someone clarify where I am going wrong? any example would help too.

from the time shifting property, if you delay a signal by t0 you multiply it's fourier transform by $ \exp(-j2\pi t0\omega)F(\omega)$, this means that each frequency gets multiplied by a different complex exponent (phase is shifted linearly with frequency). When you write shifted by kw1 kw2, this is phase in the frequency domain (which translates to constant group delay in the time domain)

Consider a linear time-invariant system with a constant magnitude of its frequency response and a phase $\phi(\omega)$:
$$H(\omega)=e^{j\phi(\omega)}\tag{1}$$
When passed through the system, a sinusoidal input signal $x(t)=\sin(\omega_0t)$ experiences a phase shift $\phi(\omega_0)$, resulting in the output signal
$$y(t)=\sin\big(\omega_0t+\phi(\omega_0)\big)\tag{2}$$
Now assume that the phase is a linear function of frequency:
$$\phi(\omega)=-\omega t_0\tag{3}$$
In this case, Eq. $(2)$ becomes
$$y(t)=\sin\big(\omega_0t-\omega_0t_0\big)=\sin\big(\omega_0(t-t_0)\big)\tag{4}$$
which shows that a linear phase causes a constant delay for a sinusoidal input, regardless of its frequency.

Thank you, that helped a lot.


how can the system have a constant time delay for different frequencies?

Suppose we have a signal:
$s(t) = \cos(\omega_1 t) + \cos(\omega_2 t)$
When this signal passes through a linear phase system with phase response  $\Omega(\omega) = k \cdot \omega$ each frequency component will be shifted in phase by an amount proportional to  $\omega$ :
$y(t) = \cos(\omega_1 t + k \cdot \omega_1) + \cos(\omega_2 t + k \cdot \omega_2)$
The phase shift can be interpreted as a time delay  $\tau = -k$  for both components, so the output effectively becomes:
$y(t) = \cos(\omega_1 (t + \tau)) + \cos(\omega_2 (t + \tau))$
Since both frequencies are delayed by the same time  $\tau$ , so this translates to a constant time delay for both frequencies.
